# Error in Dealing with Arrays C++

Tags: c++

i am getting a segment error in the below code any suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks

```
/*

 * File:   newmain.cpp
 * Author: user
 *
 * Created on 10 December, 2014, 7:18 AM
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int append(int a[], int b[], int m, int n);

int main() {


    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int b[] = {4, 5};
    int m = sizeof (a);
    int n = sizeof (b);
    append(a, b, m, n);

    return 0;

}

int append(int a[], int b[], int m, int n) {

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < m && j, n) {
        if (a[i] < b[j]) {

            cout << a[i++];

        } else if (a[i] > b[j]) {

            cout << b[j++];

        } else {

            cout << b[j++];
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){

        cout<<a[i];

    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){

        cout<<b[j];

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the code? What line is causing the segmentation fault?

Comment: You meant to put "j < n" not "j, n"

Comment: You need first to debug your code until you know which line is causing you trouble. Then you can post that to make a more informative question.

Comment: while (i < m && j, n) -- is not right. Please remove ", n" even if that compiles (?) Or what did you mean? while (i < m && j < n)?

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` returns the size of a type *in bytes*.  You have an array of `int`, so the number of elements is `sizeof a / sizeof(int)` or, better, `sizeof a / sizeof a[0]`.

Your next problem involves [the comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: @Smac19 if you look at the contents of the `append` function it is clear that the number of elements was wanted

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof (a)` is the number of bytes in the array, not the number of elements.

You could divide by the element size, `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])`.

Or you could use `std::extent<decltype(a)>::value`.

Or you could write a little function to give the size of an array:

```
template <typename T, size_t N> size_t array_size(T(&)[N]){return N;}
```

Or you could make your function a template, taking array references rather than pointers as its arguments and deducing the size from those arrays:

```
template <size_t n, size_t m>
int append(int (&a)[n], int (&b)[m]) {
    // your code here
}
```

You also have a typo in the loop condition:

```
while (i < m && j < n)
                  ^ not ,
```

Finally, you declare `append` to return `int`, but don't return anything. Either return something, or change the return type to `void`.